# is there a way to optimize query search sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have in my database full_names : ["Ann Van Heck","David Hupp","Ann Van Hecke"]

i use this query to search a term in my database :

```
select full_name FROM profiles where full_name ~  'Ann Van Heck';
```

but the problem is that it returns :

```
'Ann Van Heck'
'Ann Van Hecke'
```

but i want to have just Ann Van Heck in output

Comment: This is no MySQL syntax.  So my first suggestion is to write a query that doesn't return an error.  Or tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: select full_name FROM profiles where full_name =  'Ann Van Heck';

Comment: `~` operatop is PostgreSQL-specific, it seems, MySQL does not use it.

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` and tell us what it says.

Answer (score 0):

select full_name FROM profiles where full_name = 'Ann Van Heck';
It's worked.